# How can I use Selenium (Python) to interact with a dropdown menu created within <div> elements and no <options>?

Tags: python, selenium

I am having trouble selecting different options within a dropdown menu using selenium. It looks like the dropdown was created only using `<div>` tags without any `<options>`. I can't figure out how exactly each of the values for the drop down are being derived

HTML:
[Here is a picture of the HTML.The value "Uruguay" is one of the options in the dropdown itself. If I choose another country from the dropdown, the `<div>` updates to that country.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qXhF0.png)

Comment: FYI, I am trying to do all of this in the website for dlocal (a payment processor -https://merchant.dlocal.com/login)

Comment: Have you tried clicking your required option?
e.g. `element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[.='Uruguacy']")` then `element.click()`
(I have not tested the XPath, so better to test XPath before using it in code)

Comment: Thanks! I was able to figure out after messing around with the html. I added my answer at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out! turns out, there is an  tag after all of the . All I did was opened the drop down and then found the  element by xpath and forwarded a string for the value that I wanted to choose.

```
country_dropdown = driver.find_element_by_class_name("user-merchants")
country_dropdown.click() # open dropdown
time.sleep(5)

select_option = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='react-select-2-input']")
select_option.send_keys({insert your string here}) #add dropdown option
time.sleep(2)

select_option.send_keys(Keys.RETURN) #choose option
time.sleep(2)
```

[Field in the box is the field that is receiving the string from .send_keys()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nC9Ry.png)